# Prove that there is no finite set

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that there is no finite set of polynomials $f_1,...,f_n$ such that $\operatorname{Span}(f_1,...,f_n)=K[x]$.
How can I do a rigorous demonstration? 
I thought of basing myself on the fact that the elements of $K[x]$ are of the form $a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n$, for each $n$ there is always an $n + 1$ and therefore the span of $n$ vectors will always be contained in the $n + 1$ span.

Comment: And if the finite set contains the polynomial $1$?

Comment: Does Span mean the linear span?

Comment: $n=1$ but I tried to demonstrate it for an infinite number of elements

Comment: Yes, i mean linear span

Comment: What ring/field do the coefficients of the polynomial come from? $K$? and what is $K$, an arbitrary ring/field?

Comment: $K$ is a generic field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it suffices to come up with an infinite linearly independent set. By "infinite linearly independent set", I mean an infinite set such that every finite subset is linearly independent in the traditional finite sense. If $S$ were such a set, and a finite spanning set existed, then the space $K[x]$ would have finite dimension $n$. Taking a subset of $n + 1$ vectors from $S$ is possible, and would be linearly independent, which would be impossible to extend to a basis of $n$ vectors.

The classic example of such a set is the monomials $S = \{1, x, x^2, \ldots\}$.

If $K = \Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$, then we can think of $K[x]$ as a subspace of the vector space of functions from $K$ to $K$. The classic way to prove linear independence is to use induction and repeated differentiation. If we take a finite subset of the set of monomials $S$, then there must be a maximum degree $n$, and hence this subset is contained in the set $S_n = \{1, x, x^2, \ldots, x^n\}$.

Suppose
$$a_0 \cdot 1 + a_1 \cdot x + \ldots + a_n \cdot x^n = 0$$
as functions, i.e. for all $x \in K$. Then, differentiating both sides repeatedly, we get
\begin{align*}
a_0 \cdot 1 + a_1 \cdot x + a_2 x^2 + \ldots + a_n \cdot x^n &= 0 \\
a_1 + 2a_2 x \ldots + n a_n \cdot x^{n-1} &= 0 \\
2a_2 + \ldots + n(n-1) a_n \cdot x^{n-2} &= 0 \\
&\vdots \\
n! a_n &= 0.
\end{align*}
The final equation says that $a_n = 0$. Back-subbing into the penultimate equation says $a_{n-1} = 0$, and continuing on tells us that all coefficients must be $0$.

Thus $S'$ and hence $S$ are linearly independent (due to the arbitrary nature of $n$) and $K[x]$ cannot be spanned by any finite set.

Again, that's if $K = \Bbb{R}$ or $K = \Bbb{C}$. What if neither is true? The question itself becomes a little more curly. The problem is, looking at $K[x]$ as functions makes this false in general! In particular, consider when $K$ is a finite field. The set of functions from $K$ to $K$ is now a finite set! It is spanned by itself, and hence is finite-dimensional (with dimension $|K|$). But, somehow, we still think of polynomials as being infinite-dimensional! How is this possible?

It's possible because polynomials are not functions in this general setting. They are a formal object: basically a finite sequence of $K$, just presented differently so that we can add and multiply them in a natural way. This means that the linear independence of the monomials are linearly independent basically by definition. We define addition of these formal "polynomial" objects so that no linear combination of monomials can give you any other monomials.

So, infinite-dimensionality of $K[x]$ basically comes by definition, for arbitrary $K$.

Answer (score 1):

For a polynomial $f = a_nX^n + ... + a_1X + a_0$ with $a_n \neq 0, a_i \in K$, the degree $\deg f$ is the greatest exponent with coefficient $\neq 0$, i. e. $\deg f = n$.

There are polynomials of arbitrarily high degree: For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$: $\deg(X^n)$ = n.

Now use the fact, that for all $f, g \in K[X]$, we have $\deg (f+g) \leq \max (\deg f, \deg g)$, and for $a \in K \backslash \{0\}, f\in K[X]$, we have $\deg af = \deg f$ (just think about what happens to the coefficients when you add two polynomials or multiply a polynomial with a scalar in $K$):

Given a set $\{ f_1, ..., f_n \} \subseteq K[X]$, the degree of any linear combination $ \deg (\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i f_i) \leq \max (\deg f_1, ..., \deg f_n) $ is bounded. But this implies that for $ m > \max (\deg f_1, ..., \deg f_n) $, $X^m $ is not contained in $ \operatorname{Span}(f_1, ..., f_n) $ , but in $K[X]$.

So the $f_1, ..., f_n$ do not span $K[X]$.